# Excel-vba: Filter CSV files from folder / subfolder and copy all in 1 worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently struggling on my code. I hope anyone can help me.
Here below I adjusted a code (from the internet) so I get all files in folders and subfolders in a collection.
I want to copy the content of every csv file and paste it in a master Excel-file. Since I'm new to VBA, I'm not sure how to handle this.

```
Public Sub NonRecursiveMethod()
    Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim NameFolder

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set queue = New Collection
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set NameFolder = oApp.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select folder with CSV files", 512)
    queue.Add fso.GetFolder(NameFolder.Self.Path)

    Do While queue.Count > 0
        Set oFolder = queue(1)
        queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
        '...insert any folder processing code here...

        MsgBox "Folder = " & oFolder

        For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
            queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
        Next oSubfolder
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        '...insert any file processing code here...

        MsgBox "File = " & oFile

        Next oFile
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question though?

Comment: My question is if someone could help me with the code to filter all .csv files and
- open the csv-file
- copy all content into a temperary file
- close the csv-file
- move to the next csv-file
- paste that content under previous content in temp file
- close cvs-file and so on ...